# Laravel 5.1 query using 2 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have 2 tables: items and item_details.

items:

`id | name | shop_id`

item_details:

`id | item_id | price | delivery | ...`

I need to get all items with unique names with highest price. 
In other words I need to get a max price value from table 2 for each unique name in table 1.

I tried to use this query, but it returns only 1 row:

```
$item_details = \DB::table('item_details')
->join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'item_details.item_id')
->where('item_details.price', \DB::raw("(select max(`price`) from item_details)"))
->groupBy('name')
->get();
```

When I use `$items = Item::all();` and `$item_details = ItemDetails::all();`

```
                     <tbody>
                        @if (isset($item_details) && count($item_details))
                        @foreach($item_details as $detail)
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row" >{{ $detail->item->name}}</th>
                            <td>{{ $detail->price}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $detail->delivery}}
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        @else
                        @endif  
                    </tbody>
```

I have repetition of names, but I need unique names with highest price value for each.
Mb someone knows how to make it easier.

FOR EXAMPLE:

table 1

```
id | name | shop_id
 1    aaa   1
 2    bbb   1
 3    ccc   2
 4    ddd   1
 5    eee   3
```

table 2

```
id | item_id | price | delivery | ...
 1      1      100
 2      1      200
 3      2       50
 4      2      150
 5      3      200
 6      3      400
 7      3      700
```

result should be

```
name | price |
 aaa     200
 bbb     150
 ccc     700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic in your query is slightly off. Your where clause is saying to only return the item that has the highest price. You need to use a `group by` to get the unique values.

In raw mysql your query should look similar to 
`SELECT max(item_details.price), items.* FROM item_details left join items on item_details.item_id = items.id group by items.name;`.

**EDIT:**

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$item_details = \DB::table('item_details')
            ->select(['items.*', \DB::raw('max(`price`)')])
            ->join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'item_details.item_id')
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->get();
```

Comment: ye sorry, I copied the wrong query, there should be ->groupBy('name'), I've updated my question, Anyway it shows the unique names, but with random price (not the hight for concrete name).